# QML textInput how to handle selection and escape

Tags: qt, qml

I am building a QML application and I have a `TextInput` component as follows:

```
TextInput {
                id: editableTextInput
                text: styleData.value
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                selectionColor: 'darkgray'
                selectedTextColor: 'white'
                font.pixelSize: 14
                font.family: "AvantGarde-Medium"

                onEditingFinished: {
                    // TO DO: Handle new text
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        editableTextInput.selectAll()
                    }
                }
            }
```

At the moment, the way it stands is when the user clicks on the text, it selects the whole text and then I can start typing and the whole text will be replaced but I want the user to give a bit more finer control. For one, initially the user selects the full text and then if they click again, it should basically put the cursor at the current position. Also, the escape key should basically restore the old text and cancel the whole operation.

These are standard ways for text input. I was wondering if I have to program all of this explicitly or is there a way to get this behaviour with the `TextInput` control.

Comment: You have to code it to customize it using the Keys qml module to catch the key events and the MouseArea to capture the clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you don't need to use MouseArea for this. Hook `activeFocus` to decide when to select the text (on initial click, `activeFocus` will become true), store the old text, and restore it when editing is finished if escape was pressed.

I think this gets you a good part of the way to what you want:

```
import QtQuick 2.6

TextInput {
    text: "Hello world!" + index
    font.pixelSize: 24
    width: 300
    height: 30

    // Store the previous text for restoring it if we cancel
    property string oldText

    // Lets us know that the user is cancelling the save
    property bool cancelling

    Keys.onEscapePressed: {
        // Cancel the save, and deselect the text input
        cancelling = true
        focus = false
    }

    onEditingFinished: {
        if (cancelling) {
            // When cancelling, restore the old text, and clear state.
            text = oldText
            oldText = ""
            cancelling = false
        } else {
            // TO DO: Handle new text
        }
    }

    onActiveFocusChanged: {
        // When we first gain focus, save the old text and select everything for clearing.
        if (activeFocus) {
            oldText = text
            selectAll()
        }
    }
}
```